# Mysql Index misbehave in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, indexing, mysql-workbench, mysql2

I have an rails app hosted with Mysql, there is a **reservations** table with index set in column **rescheduled_reservation_id** (nullable).

In my rails app there are two part to query reservation by  rescheduled_reservation_id fields as below:

```html
Transit::Reservation.find_by(rescheduled_reservation_id: 25805)
```

and produce the following log output:

```html
Transit::Reservation Load (60.3ms)  SELECT  `transit_reservations`.* FROM `transit_reservations` WHERE `transit_reservations`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `transit_reservations`.`rescheduled_reservation_id` = 25805 LIMIT 1
```

However the other part of the app:

```html
Transit::Reservation.where(rescheduled_reservation_id: 25805).last
```

with the log output belows

```
Transit::Reservation Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  `transit_reservations`.* FROM `transit_reservations` WHERE `transit_reservations`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `transit_reservations`.`rescheduled_reservation_id` = 25805  ORDER BY `transit_reservations`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

As clearly seen the first query

```
Transit::Reservation Load (60.3ms)  SELECT  `transit_reservations`.* FROM `transit_reservations` WHERE `transit_reservations`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `transit_reservations`.`rescheduled_reservation_id` = 25805 LIMIT 1
```

took up to 60ms, the index might not have been used properly comparing to 2ms in this

```
Transit::Reservation Load (2.3ms)  SELECT  `transit_reservations`.* FROM `transit_reservations` WHERE `transit_reservations`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `transit_reservations`.`rescheduled_reservation_id` = 25805  ORDER BY `transit_reservations`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

[image]

I also tried to debug further by running **explain** on both queries, I got back the same result i.e the index rescheduled_reservation_id being used

[image]

Is there anyone experiencing with this issue? I am wondering whether rails mysql connection ( I am using mysql2 gem ) might cause Mysql server to not choose the right index

Answer (score 2):

It's Rare, but Normal.

The likely answer is that the first occurrence did not find the blocks it needed cached in the buffer_pool.  So, it had to fetch them from disk.  On a plain ole HDD, a Rule of Thumb is 10ms per disk hit.  So, maybe there were 6 blocks that it needed to fetch, leading to 60.3ms.

Another possibility is that other activities were interfering, thereby slowing down this operation.

2.3ms is reasonable for a simple query like that the can be performed entirely with cached blocks in RAM.

Was the server recently restarted?  After a restart, there is nothing in cache.  Is the table larger than `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  If so, that would lead to 60ms happening sporadically -- blocks would get bumped out.  (Caveat:  The buffer_pool should not be made so big that 'swapping' occurs.)

A block is 16KB; it contains some rows of data or rows of index or nodes of a BTree.  Depending on the size of the table, even that 'point query' might have needed to look at 6 blocks or more.

If you don't get 2.3ms *most* of the time, we should dig deeper.  (I have hinted at sizes to investigate.)

Comment: I tried the above queries again and again but the result still not so different ( ~60ms vs ~2ms). FYI It uses SSD. I have to check innodb_buffer_pool_size. Thank for a lot tips.

Comment: @channaly - was it alternating between 60 and 2?  Or randomly doing 60 vs 2?  Or a variety of other values?  Was anything else touching that table during your testing?  (60 made sense with HDD, but is unreasonably high for SSD.  Getting 60 again messes with my theory.  Etc.)  Are there any `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns?  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I ran same query many times the result did not bias much ( ~60ms, ~61ms, ~59ms, ..) vs ~1ms, ~2ms, ...) I don't think it is an issue of caching. I do have one text field and no blob. what is the matter with the text field?

Comment: @channaly - large text/blob columns are stored "off-record", hence take extra disk hit(s).  Was there only one row in each case?

Comment: I see. But in my case the two queries hit the same row, so if it were because of disk access it should affect both of them.

Comment: Well, I am stumped.  If you come up with something that is different about the cases, I may come up with a better explanation of the significant difference in timing.

Comment: Thank a lot. you gave a lot of insight. I continue to debug it further.